# "table definition changed" despite restore point creation after table create/alter

Tags: oracle

`FLASHBACK TABLE` to a restore point fails when that restore point was created immediately after a table change.  The below code only works if there is a sleep between certain steps.

```
SQL> DROP TABLE TEST_TABLE;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE AS SELECT 1 A FROM DUAL;

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;

Table altered.

SQL> --Sleep required here to prevent error on flashback.
SQL> DROP RESTORE POINT TEST_RESTORE_POINT;

Restore point dropped.

SQL> CREATE RESTORE POINT TEST_RESTORE_POINT;

Restore point created.

SQL> FLASHBACK TABLE TEST_TABLE TO RESTORE POINT TEST_RESTORE_POINT;
FLASHBACK TABLE TEST_TABLE TO RESTORE POINT TEST_RESTORE_POINT
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01466: unable to read data - table definition has changed
```

Why is a delay required and is there a way to eliminate it?

Comment: You don't have any `PARALLEL=TRUE` anywhere, do you?

Comment: @MikeNakis This problem is reproducible when run one-step-at-a-time.  It failed for me on the latest version, 12.1.0.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This oddity might be caused by `SMON` process which is responsible to keep track between SCNs and timestamps which flashback query relies upon. There is a mapping table `SYS.SMON_SCN_TIME` where every 5 minutes a new record is inserted `SMON`.

Internally during the `FLASHBACK TABLE` executes a command `INSERT /*+ APPEND */ into SYS_TEMP_FBT SELECT /*+ FBTSCAN FULL(S) PARALLEL(S, DEFAULT) */ :1, :2, :3, rowid, SYS_FBT_INSDEL FROM "<schema>."TEST_TABLE" as of SCN :4 S` (notice a table `SYS_TEMP_FBT` is created in the same schema) which uses this mapping.

Up to Oracle 10.2 you needed to wait up to whole 5 minutes to succeed with FLASHBACK query on a new/altered object. In 11.1 the `TIM_SCN_MAP` column was introduced to make the mapping more fine grained. Maximum of 100 mappings is stored in one value which makes roughly 3 seconds precision in timestamp to SCN mapping.

I tried many things but I don't think you can do anything about it but wait around 3 seconds to avoid the error because this is handled asynchronously by background process without any user control.

Comment: That makes sense.  I found independently that the required time-to-wait was about 3 seconds.